# As a YT channel owner can I set up next video to be played in 'Up Next' section?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Title pretty much sums it up. I wonder if it's possible to set certain videos to be played in "Up next" section (and not in playlist).
I have found out that these videos are selected automatically.[[1]](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/92651?hl=en) But sometimes, when you watch video from certain channel, the video in "Up next" section is taken from the same channel. And I wonder if you can override this video somewhere in admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have browsed the YouTube help forum, your question was answered [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/yTXM-o3lMAs).

> The "Up next" is just the first video in the related videos. You
>   cannot control the related videos directly, but if you have similar
>   tags and descriptions across your video, there is a higher chance that
>   one of your videos will show up.

Also, if you'll come across the [documentation you have provided](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6342839), it was suggested that:

> Your activity on YouTube, Google, and Chrome may influence your
>   YouTube search results, recommendations on the Home page, in-app
>   notifications, and suggested videos among other places.
>
> There are several ways to influence these recommendations and search
>   results. You can remove specific videos from your [watch
>   history](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/95725) and queries
>   from your search history, pause your watch and search history, or
>   start fresh by clearing your watch and [search
>   history](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57711).